# Gredlew taskname - command not running Android studio terminal

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, sonarqube, gradlew

I was trying to run a Gradle command on android studio terminal but it shows 
like:-
`'grdlew' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.`

the exact command was `'gradlew sonar'`
Please guide me how to solve this.

Comment: try with `.\gradlew`

Comment: Thanks, @VivekI tried with that way also but it's showing same as above .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After spending a lot of time on it and above solutions also not working for me
I found one thing that is my system doesn't have Gradle installed so I installed Gradle into my system and provide the bin folder path in a system environment. Like
i.e.

```
PATH
```

```
D:\gradle-6.0.1\bin
```

And then go your project directory and open the cmd window there by typing cmd in the file path view and run gradle query like this

gradle sonarqube

-Dsonar.projectKey=$REPLACE_WITH_GENERATED_keyCreatedOnSonarqube

-Dsonar.host.url=http://localhost:9000

-Dsonar.login=$REPLACE_WITH_GENERATED_TOKEN_OnSonarqube

And this made my day
I hope this will help anyone else also

Answer (score 0):

1. `gradlew` command is available in your project directory. If you are trying to run this command from somewhere else it will throw an error.
2. Also, `gradlew` command package is automatically generated by `Android Studio` when you create a new project. It will also prompt you to generate new gradle wrapper when you open the project.

Comment: thanks, @Niraj Yes but it's not working from the android studio terminal its throws the error as I mentioned above.